# How to modify QUERY to fill a column with BLANKS

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to populate columns **Product Name** and **Supplier**. However, the template I am filling in also has Description in column C. How can I amend the QUERY formula I have to essentially say skip column C and populate relevant data in column D (of course I'd insert the relevant column inside SELECT..)? Or alternatively, can I amend the QUERY to fill the Description column with blanks and then move on to the Supplier column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something alike this:

```
=QUERY(A1:B4,"Select A,' ',B LABEL ' '''")
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

QUERY accepts "anything" as the select clause, so you can do:

```
=QUERY(data,"select D, '', F offset 1 label '' ''",0)
```

Or without all the quotes:

```
=QUERY(data,"select D, 0/0, F offset 1 label 0/0 ''",0)
```